# How to improve the performance of android apps without the ndk?

Tags: android

How to improve the performance of android apps without the ndk? How can I write CPU intense application without knowing c++?

Comment: You could write them in C, or find some other compiled language on Android (ocaml, haskell, ....)

Comment: These are some good tips: http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html Java should run fairly fast with JIT compilers and such. Are you already running into performance issues?

Comment: Read this: The best optimizer is between your ears http://www.nondot.org/sabre/Mirrored/GraphicsProgrammingBlackBook/gpbb1.pdf

Comment: Why is the question tagged [C++] when you explicitly do not want to use C++. Or do you want to use C++ without knowing C++?

Comment: you are right I obviously don't want to use c++

Comment: I remember one google video on programming games in java, to make java code efficent enough you should code in it like in pure C, this means preallocate all objects/array before any main logic loops. Minimize gc executions.

Comment: I would start with writing the app first the best you can, and then optimize any inefficient algorithms and object usage (ie, use structs where possible). Finally do some profiling looking for cpu and memory bottlenecks.

Comment: My code is fast. Android is slow.

Comment: What kind of processing are you doing (math, data processing (ie GUI forms for displaying DB data), sound, etc ...).

Comment: Make sure you are leveraging what Android already has (ie, list adapters, drawables, life-time overrides: onCreate, onResume) to the fullest potential. Try not to work against it.

Comment: You should definitely learn about the life-time methods, the messaging queue (otherwise you'll get tons of exceptions accessing views that havent been drawn yet), the rendering process http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html . Once you get single view working, look into Fragments.

Comment: Thanks, you can post this as an answer also.

Comment: Android's threading model is also very important to understand. Give ViewTreeObserver a look. ViewPager and FragmentPagerAdapter for Fragments. Definitely look into subclassing you're own "custom" views; this is great for overriding the OnMeasure and OnLayout methods - put a lot of print outs in them, especially a stack trace, to learn how android draws views.

Comment: That is impossible to answer in general. The techniques to "improve the performance" of an OpenGL animation would be different than the techniques to "improve the performance" of a database operation. Use Traceview to determine where your problem is, then return to StackOverflow to ask a more focused question.

Comment: @We'reAllMadHere "My code is fast. Android is slow." No for the second sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(I need to clean this up when I get a chance, and will continue to add to it, if the question doesn't get closed. **CommonsWare is right though, everything I say here doesn't apply to game programming, but building an app from built-in android widgets**).*

I would start with writing the app first the best you can, and then optimize any inefficient algorithms and object usage (ie, use structs where possible, return non-reusable strings from a function instead of storing them in a global static variable). Finally do some profiling looking for cpu bottlenecks and memory leaks.

Make sure you are leveraging what Android already has (ie, list adapters, drawables, life-time overrides: onCreate, onResume) to the fullest potential. Try not to work against it.

You should definitely learn about the life-time methods, the messaging queue (otherwise you'll get tons of exceptions accessing views that havent been drawn yet), the rendering process

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html

Once you get single view working, look into Fragments.

Android's threading model is also very important to understand. Give ViewTreeObserver a look. ViewPager and FragmentPagerAdapter for Fragments. Definitely look into subclassing you're own "custom" views; this is great for overriding the OnMeasure and OnLayout methods - put a lot of print outs in them, especially a stack trace, to learn how android draws views.

You also want to learn about services, and how they can run in either the same or separate process as your main activity. Android has direct support for the Command pattern, and is implemented with services. It also supports MVC, and if setup correctly, if you edit a GUI-list's associated list data structure, then the GUI will automatically be updated to reflect that change.

---

If you ever get into a situation where your getting NullReferenceExceptions when trying to access a views member property through a reference variable, say, to figure out the length of your view:

```
view.get_length()
```

I usually find one of three options to work around this

1. Post the operation in a runnalbe
2. Subclass the view in question and try to access the view's properties in onMeasure or onLayout
3. Attempt to access the property from the onResume() override of your Activity.